# Semiconductors:LED

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Given the below diagram,
[image: absorption spectrum]

The text further reads why Germanium is better choice in solar cells

And the next paragraph says

PbS ..(ref figure)

> Radiation will be absorbed on top layer and would not reach the depletion region

what is the meaning of this part 
[image: intensity absorbed]

Comment: Sorry let me edit that,*done please see and help me if possible.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I cannot understand the last paragraph **Radiation will be absorbed on top layer and would not reach the depletion region **

Comment: Wavelengths well above band gap are strongly absorbed. Since there must be a layer above the depletion layer, you don't want it to absorb strongly.